# Android Circular image with pointer

Tags: java, android

[image: Google Map Marker]

I am developing Android application, in my application I have to show the user profile image as shown in this image. I had used CircularImage but I need to have the pointer in the bottom, can anyone help me how to create circular image with pointer the bottom

Answer (score 0):

you can set your pointer(blue background) as background for `ImageView` and set user image as `src` in `bitmap`
also you need to round your `bitmap`,by this method you can earn circular bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap toRoundBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float roundPx;
    float left, top, right, bottom, dst_left, dst_top, dst_right, dst_bottom;
    if (width <= height) {
        roundPx = width / 2.0f;
        top = 0;
        bottom = width;
        left = 0;
        right = width;
        height = width;
        dst_left = 0;
        dst_top = 0;
        dst_right = width;
        dst_bottom = width;
    } else {
        roundPx = height / 2.0f;
        float clip = (width - height) / 2;
        left = clip;
        right = width - clip;
        top = 0;
        bottom = height;
        width = height;
        dst_left = 0;
        dst_top = 0;
        dst_right = height;
        dst_bottom = height;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect src = new Rect((int) left, (int) top, (int) right,
            (int) bottom);
    final Rect dst = new Rect((int) dst_left, (int) dst_top,
            (int) dst_right, (int) dst_bottom);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(dst);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
    return output;
}
```

and set round bitmap as src for your ImageView:

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(toRoundBitmap(mBitMap));
```

for better view set `android:scaleType="fitStart"` in your `ImageView` tag in xml

Comment: this is a small preview of my work. this method make your image circular then you can use it in a imageview with your custom bg.like image above.